# Is there a site problem with uploading images to answers?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, uploading-images, not-actually-fixed

I can't seem to be able to upload images.

I get this message: -

**An error occurred when uploading the image:**

It also happened yesterday but, it seemed to be fixed about 0930 this morning. But, it's still giving problems. This is a photograph of the error message that I uploaded via another computer: -

[image: screenshot showing error message]

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've just uploaded some images (up to the point where I see they have got onto the image server & have been given URLs - I didn't actually post that answer). It's possible that there are either intermittent or location-specific problems. Can you update your question & clarify what point in the process you get that error? I guess you hit Ctrl+G, browse to an image (or paste it into the dialog) - that shows a thumbnail only in the dialog box. Then click "Add picture" which does the upload & should show the picture full size in the draft Q/A. Does the error appear there?

Comment: @SamGibson I get to the image upload box and usually it's fine but, it comes up with the error above instead. I can see a miniature the image was captured but it ends with the error message. It does appear to be working at the moment but, I'm on a different PC now so, it might be a glitch associated with the other laptop.

Comment: I understand you're not getting the error right now (as you say, different PC or perhaps an intermittent problem with the image server, like has happened before). Just to be clear, you said: "it ends with the error message". Do you remember if that was after you clicked the "Add picture" button? As far as I understand the process, everything *before* clicking that button is local to the device (PC, tablet etc.). Clicking that button does the actual upload to the image server. I'm just trying to make sure that if this does need to be reported, then we're as clear as possible for the devs. TY

Comment: The error message I got was contained within the upload box after I pressed the upload image button. I'll add a photo using the laptop that appears to work.

Comment: Thanks. Just as an FYI, I don't see anyone reporting image upload problems recently on Meta.SE. So that suggests any problems might be intermittent enough that no-one has been affected enough to bother doing that, or perhaps they affect our site only (though I don't know if that's possible). If only 1 of your PCs is affected, obviously that points away from being a widespread problem.

Comment: Both are affected now. Just tried to load it using a 2nd computer and it didn't work. Thinking...... I tried scaling down the image to 50% but no good either. It did work earlier on the original laptop but it doesn't work on either now.

Comment: "Both are affected now." I can still upload OK (*shrug*). Odd.

Comment: It's working intermittently now. I'll hopefully be able to post the screen shot... No, it's gone again.

Comment: It works every time on codidact (that other place)

Comment: I managed to get an upload of the screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Eob.png

Comment: @Andyaka I can't repeat the failure at the moment. As a test, just edited your [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/699222/101063) to include an image of the section I think you were referring to, but having an issue with uploading images. Also, I searched for the error you had but couldn't find an other reports of the same error message.

Comment: @Andyaka - Like *Chester* in the last comment, I also can't reproduce it (although obviously you're having a problem - no doubt). As you'll see from the [escalation process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642), we're only supposed to escalate to SE if other people have reproduced it. Therefore at the moment, that's what we're waiting for - reports from other people. If we get that, then we can justify escalation. || Just FYI, the reduced SE staff at weekends mean I doubt we would get a response today, even if escalated today. Let's see if anyone else reports it...

Comment: @SamGibson no problemo

Comment: it is a wider issue, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396425/cant-upload-images

Comment: @rene yeah looks like it started small, nobody noticed (who should and can fix it) and now it's 100% broken for everyone on all sites. I won't be surprised if this will still be broken next month.

Comment: @SamGibson any reason [tag:status-review] isn't being used here? On Meta Stack Exchange adding the tag means throwing the bug to the developer's backlog where they have chance to see it. Without it, well, they won't see it as they don't browse the meta sites themselves. I can start a separate discussion about it here if you prefer, my point is that perhaps the bug could have been fixed "while small" if the proper people (i.e. SE devs) would have seen it.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda - Yes, there *was* a reason. As I explained a few comments above, the [escalation process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642) requires that other people are able to reproduce the problem before adding that tag (e.g. confirmation that it's not a problem with only 1 user's equipment). I checked at the time it was reported on here, and no-one had reported it on Meta.SE nor were other people reporting it here. So that is what we were waiting for, as other users here were having no problem. However now that you have reproduced it, I'm allowed to (and did) add that tag.

Comment: [there is an error with uploading the picture of it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/699439/how-can-i-add-the-same-resistance-to-two-resistors) <-- from EE today

Comment: @Andyaka - Yes, there are several questions where people are seeing the problem here on EE today :( FYI SE staff (*JNat* - one of the CMs) has said [they are actively investigating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396425/cant-upload-images#comment1325889_396425). If anyone cares I could explain a workaround of how to use other hosting, but that should only be temporary (because - reasons) and images posted elsewhere should be copied back to SE hosting when that's fixed. So it would allow images to be displayed now, but also results in extra work when the SE hosting is fixed...

Comment: SE image uploads are currently working. I'm waiting for an official update from SE before declaring this resolved.

Comment: This is now confirmed as resolved - see [the answer from Slate](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9996).

Answer (score 5):

This issue has been resolved - quoting myself [from Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396425/cant-upload-images):

> Thank you for making this post. We diagnosed the issue with Imgur uploads and reached out to Imgur for support. They responded quickly, investigated, and resolved the issue.
>
> We should now have full function for image uploads network-wide. Please feel free to point any per-site Meta questions on the topic to this answer.

Comment: Thanks for that, Slate!

Comment: This is still a problem as of 09:06 February 1st 2024. Tried 4 times to no avail. Same message. I tried ten times and it failed every one. I went to Codidact to try the same thing and, it worked first time.

Comment: OK, the problem occurs when directly copying a section of an image from "paint" but, if I save that image to my desktop and use the add image button and drag the saved file into the window it works. However, this is an unacceptable state of affairs even if it is a kind of work-around.

Comment: Readers, please note that this wasn't the fix and the problem is still outstanding. See newer question here: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9999/is-there-a-site-problem-with-uploading-images-to-answers-same-problem-as-before

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer to show that we still have a problem. That problem **is exactly the same as it always has been** (since earlier in the week).

This was a screenshot taken about 10 minutes ago showing the bottom of Voltage spike's answer and me trying to "add a new" answer incorporating the screenshot.

[image]

As you can see, the image upload fails. I then tried using CTRL-G then CTRL-V but that failed also. however, I managed to get the above image into this "answer" by

- saving the screenshot as untitled.png
- opening the landscape image-insert icon
- dragging the image across

This is the same problem I've been facing since I first reported it. The only thing that has changed is that I've found a laborious and unpleasant workaround.

Comment: I don't think adding this problem (which is not reproducible by me) into the original report (which *was* reproducible by others), is the correct thing to do. Uploads to Imgur are now clearly working and that was the original problem you kindly reported.  IMHO this needs to be looked into separately, as *Slate* has advised [on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396425/cant-upload-images/396437?noredirect=1#comment1326171_396437). || Even if the root causes do end up being discovered to be linked, the symptoms are different enough to be investigated separately IMHO.

Comment: Sam, I'm not adding a problem; I'm saying that my original post (at the top of this page) has not been addressed. And, I've supplemented this page with this answer that shows that it works if you save the image then drag and drop. Unacceptable of course and, clearly indicative that something has gone wrong since the weekend that is still wrong and was misleadingly reported as being fixed by slate.

Comment: Andyaka - "*I'm saying that my original post (at the top of this page) has not been addressed.*" I respectfully disagree. You (and everyone else) were not able to upload an image *at all* on 30 Jan, before SE (Slate & co) engaged with Imgur. Now you *can* upload an image, albeit via a different process. || I can't reproduce your described problem (using either a direct paste into the edit box (as you normally do), or using Ctrl+G (as I normally do)) - it all just works for me. So IMHO even though that generic error message you see is the same, this should be investigated via a new Meta post.

Comment: OK a new meta post it shall be.

Comment: Thanks for starting a new Meta topic. For the benefit of other site members, here is the link: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9999/is-there-a-site-problem-with-uploading-images-to-answers-same-problem-as-before || To avoid anyone duplicating effort on this report *here*, I'm locking this answer. All investigation of this report should be done in the new linked Meta post above.