# Is there a site problem with uploading images to answers (same problem as before)?

Tags: support, bug, uploading-images

I (still) can't seem to be able to upload images in the way I have done so normally over the last ten years or so. I have to take a much more protracted route that looks (to me) like a site bug (despite others saying that they can't replicate it).

I'll also add that my upload rate is quite poor at 200 kbps (in case this is a factor to whatever might have changed). It happens on both my laptops in case anyone thinks it might be related to a specific PC.

I get this message: -

\$\color{red}{\text{An error occurred when uploading the image:}}\$

**What I normally do** when uploading an image and, importantly what hasn't worked reliably since Sunday 28th of January 2024, is copy a section directly from paint.exe and directly CTRL-V it to the **body of my post**. This doesn't work at all reliably.

**What I was asked to try** also doesn't work any better (CTRL-G and CTRL-V). CTRL-G opens up the image-selection box in case anyone is interested. Everyone should know what CTRL-V does of course.

This question is highly related to [a question I raised on Sunday January 28th 2024 to which a solution has still not been found](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9994/is-there-a-site-problem-with-uploading-images-to-answers/9998?noredirect=1#comment21444_9998).

It's the same question and is NOT FIXED by the answer to which my previous question received an [incorrect answer](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9996/20218).

However, there is a torturous workaround that also seems to work: -

- saving the screenshot as (for instance) *untitled.png*
- opening the landscape image-insert icon
- dragging the image across to the image selection box

I believe this problem began happening sometime Saturday 27th January. That's when I first saw it.

Comment: Thanks for starting a new topic. However right now, this seems inaccurate by omission: AIUI the problem is that you can't upload an image **using drag & drop**, but you *can* by uploading from a local file. Saying that you "can't seem to be able to upload images" on its own is therefore misleading. Let's try to narrow down the specifics of *this* problem, to avoid it being lumped together with the previous problem, as that doesn't help anyone. || While I could edit the question, of course, I need *you* to add more clarification to the problem *you* are having, as I can't reproduce it. TY

Comment: (In other words, please try to make this question self-contained, with a full & detailed problem description. Sure, mention the previous one, but as always, don't rely on people  reading that one. TY)

Comment: @SamGibson it should be much improved now.

Comment: Thanks for the added detail. However are you sure rev 2 is accurate? It still says that you "*can't seem to be able to upload images*". However you later describe how you can upload images. Those parts seem to contradict each other. || As I commented above, I think the first sentence is the part which is misleading (implying that you're unable to upload images *all the time*) - but you didn't change that despite my previous comment, so you seem clear on that part. || Since I *can* upload images, we don't yet have the necessary repro to be able to escalate to SE, per their escalation process :(

Comment: As I explained: (a) We need clarification on why you are saying that you can't upload images. I *think* you can, based on what you say later, but this needs clarification. (b) You said that image upload: "hasn't worked **reliably** since Sunday 28th of January 2024*" (my bold). I want to focus on the "when" aspect and when it is/was intermittent. We know you had unreliable uploading from 28-30th and then (like the rest of us) total failure. But what about after the changes which *Slate* explained? Has "paste-type" uploading *ever* worked since then? Does "file upload" *always* work now? TY

Comment: I've updated my question. Paste has worked intermittently throughout. At first I thought it was always bad then sometimes it worked 1 out of 3 and, today it worked 0/10 @SamGibson <-- file upload has worked 3/3 (maybe 4/4) i.e. 100% at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the update. (a) I've tried to replicate your problem in my "non-answer" - but it always works for me. I did throttle my link speed to 200 kB/s for that test. Just to clarify - you said 200 kb/s upload speed. Does that mean 200 kbits/s i.e. approx 20 kBytes/s? Or 200 kBytes/s? I used the latter (200 kBytes/s) for my test. I can repeat it at 20 kBytes/s if needed. (b) I understand that *today*, your drag&drop upload process fails 100% of the time, but the file upload process works 100% of the time. IMHO we should focus on behaviour today, not the *intermittent* problem from 28-30th.

Comment: Bits not bytes unfortunately but, it's been like this for years @SamGibson

Comment: I just double-checked the settings I used and I actually set it up wrongly for my earlier test. I had set it to 200 kbits/s, not the 200kBytes/s I thought I set it to! So I actually did reproduce the 200 kbits/s upload speed you mentioned (I set the same download speed as well).

Comment: Update 2 Feb {1/4}: No-one denies you're having an issue. However I can't repro it and I don't see any other reports of a *current* problem here or on Meta.SE. || Unfortunately, because the upload error message is completely generic, we must be careful not to assume that the cause for you *now*, is the same as the cause from 28-30 Jan (which SE report has been fixed by Imgur). || The timing of this problem starting for you is certainly suspicious, but why aren't others reporting the same problem now??

Comment: {2/4} If "drag&drop upload" failure is still 100% reproducible for you (is that true?) then some troubleshooting approaches include looking for what is different in your config (h/w, browser version & settings etc.) which could be relevant and which others *might* be able to try changing to match yours (but just as an anti-example - I no longer run Win7, so if you were using that, then I can't attempt to repro it). || Another approach is for you to try changing your setup to match mine (Win10, Brave & Firefox browsers) if yours is currently different.

Comment: {3/4} However there are many possible variations that are difficult to identify individually (e.g. browser settings) or difficult / impossible for someone else to reproduce exactly (e.g. your internet connection). || Another approach is for you to make any large change, especially if it makes your setup more "typical" e.g. try using a completely different PC at a public library. Or take your laptop to a coffee shop and use their WiFi etc. I can't guess here what options are available for you to try.

Comment: {4/4}  Depending on what those options are, there could be several differences between that test config and your original config. The point is not to try to identify a specific change in advance, just to gather data points of which configs work and which don't. Then we can compare them, looking for differences. Until someone else can repro this, there's no point to (and we're not supposed to) escalate this to SE, as they will just say (as *Slate* has said) that they don't see a systemic problem. || Any suggestions on how you want to proceed?

Comment: @SamGibson I did a CTRL-V to the body of an answer (that I subsequently discarded of course) and I got a good result of 2 out of 12 attempts. It worked on the fifth and twelfth attempt.

Comment: I then did a drag-image-to-the-box test and it worked three times out of twelve. It worked on the fifth, the seventh and the twelfth. I then did a browse and upload and it worked 6 out of the 12 times. It failed on the 2nd, 6th, 7th, 8th, 11th and 12th attempt. Marginally pointing to more success with the browse.

Comment: As I said before, it's not nice but if I keep clicking it will work, I don't think anyone can do anything else until someone else makes a similar report. I'm on W10 btw but I don't get out and never with my laptops. I might try it using my phone as the link. Nothing more you can do Sam. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Andy, I learned some stuff. (a) Neither "drag&drop" nor "file browse" uploads 100% fail nor 100% work today. That *seems* like a change from yesterday, when "file browse" uploads worked 3/3 (or 4/4) and "drag&drop" worked 0/10. (b) Today's tests show there *may* be a difference in reliability between "drag&drop" & "file browse" reliability. That is odd. (c) The poor rate of success you have suggests to me that if someone else was suffering this, then IMHO *surely* they would be reporting it (?).

Comment: (d) I am suspicious that *perhaps* your internet link *may* be part of the issue. Although in my tests I duplicated the 200 kbits/s upload speed that you mentioned, there are other possible link characteristics that could be involved (e.g. latency & packet loss) and those are harder (potentially *much* harder) to measure at your end, and then for someone else to replicate. They might also not be consistent characteristics.

Comment: (e) If you have a reasonable mobile phone signal strength there, and can spare a little bit of data allowance, then yes, please do your suggested test using the phone as the internet link instead of your usual one (ADSL or whatever it is). Ideally, please try to replicate your tests of 12 attempts each, to upload ideally the same (or at least similar sized) images as you tried yesterday, via "drag&drop" and then "file browse".

Comment: Changing the internet connection is one of those "large changes" I had in mind (I was thinking to try a coffee shop's wifi, but your phone's data is a good test too, *if* we have confidence in that connection).

Comment: (f) One final thing: When an image upload fails, how long after you click the "Add picture" button does the "An error occurred when uploading the image" message appear? Is it instantly after clicking the button? Or is it (sometimes or always) a (variable?) number of seconds after you clicked that button? || I realise you might want to stop trying things at any point. These comments are not pushing you to do stuff if you don't want to, but also are a log of my thoughts now, in case we do need to pick this up again in future. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson it's quite variable. Sometimes it's about a second and other times it can take over ten seconds to register a fail. I have no problem trying stuff out and I'll try a mobile tether tomorrow.

Comment: Re: "*Sometimes it's about a second and other times it can take over ten seconds to register a fail.*" Aha!!! OK, I'll reply more later (family stuff here now & I need to test something). But in short, I *think* it's something about your internet connection, which is the reason why you are affected. || If you have time, please do repeat using your phone as the link, as you mentioned. (Just to be clear, I think we both mean using your phone as a WiFi hotspot, so you would still be using the same laptop & browser etc., just using mobile data to provide the WiFi connection to the laptop.) TY

Comment: It means the same thing I believe -->[Share a mobile connection by hotspot or tethering on Android](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9059108?hl=en-GB#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20your,%2DFi%2C%20Bluetooth%20or%20USB.)

Comment: Andy - (a) Re: tethering - yes, I'm just making sure we both mean using WiFi between the laptop & phone, not any other tethering options e.g. Bluetooth, USB etc. :) (b) Re: uploading an image - monitoring the JS code, I see multiple steps to the process. But the main point is that, after clicking the "Add image" button (and an initial exchange with a server) the image upload starts in the background. At 200 kb/s and (e.g.) a few hundred kB of image file, that takes several seconds. IMHO a big clue to suspect "flaky comms" is that the error message appears at variable times into that upload.

Comment: (c) Also, I just noticed that the error message you've been having is *different* to the one caused by the server issue on 30 Jan (see the [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/QwRTQM4.png) on that [Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396425)). My *suspicion* is that *by coincidence* you started to have a *different* problem starting late on 27th Jan, as you mentioned. Then there was a server problem on 30th. That got fixed, but if your problem was (is) different, then even after that server failure has been fixed, you will still have "your" problem.

Comment: The different error message in that Meta.SE post, and the one reported by you in both your Meta posts on EE, are consistent with yours being a different problem (also it's not a reproducible failure, it's not being reported by others, etc.). This isn't the only possibility, but it fits the evidence I see so far. If you can try using the phone as a wifi hotspot, then let's see how that works and whether it points towards or away from that hypothesis. TY

Comment: I got 12/12 when tethering my laptop via USB to my mobile phone so, it looks like an internet thing or, an overly eager time-out setting on the SE servers? Like I say, it's been like this for years and I've never had that message until last weekend @SamGibson

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer - just to show that pasting images from the Windows clipboard directly to this answer box to upload them, is always working for me. They are all screengrabs from different parts of the Tektronix home page https://www.tek.com/en - I uploaded each one with my internet link throttled to 200 kbit/s upload & download speed:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]